# How can I include a Users picker in a custom field type?

Tags: users, custom-fieldtype

I would like to include a Users picker in a custom field type. Not sure if this is possible and practical.

Do you know how I can accomplish this, or can you point me in the right direction for self-education?

I see there is no users macro in `/app/templates/_includes/forms.html`, `/app/fieldtypes/UsersFieldType.php` has almost nothing in it, and I don't know enough about the system yet to know where else to look for ideas.

Comment: `craft/app/templates/_includes/forms/elementSelect.html` might be what your looking for, if that helps at all.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks @DouglasMcDonald! That lead me down a whole new rabbit hole, which quickly filled with water and other mixed metaphors.

Comment: haha... I know that feeling.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your requirements, but you could build a "Users Picker" with the [Dynamic Fields](https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-dynamicfields) plugin. You would basically need to do the same in its settings to build your select options as you'd do in a custom plugin.

You get your users with `craft.users` and then build an array with "label" and "value" keys using the `merge` filter.

Pass that array into the Dynamic Fields' settings or build the select options with the `forms.selectField` macro in your own plugin.

```
{% set users = craft.users.group('clients') %}

{% set userOptions = [] %}
{% for user in users %}
    {% set userOptions = userOptions|merge([{ label: user.friendlyName, value: user.id }]) %}
{% endfor %}

{{ forms.selectField({
    label: 'User'|t,
    id: id,
    name: name,
    options: userOptions,
    value: value ? value
}) }}
```

Comment: Thank you this is great, but I was hoping for the native Users picker that spawns a modal. There may be enough options that a select dropdown would be unwieldy. Due to time constraints I'll probably have to just use a separate Users field for now. Thanks again!